# Do all permanent lighting fixtures need to be switched, per NEC?

Tags: electrical

I just have a quick question about code-compliance and permanent lighting fixtures. At one of the residences I maintain, we have some rather lengthy hallways which are located in the center of the 2nd floor, a lot of this upper floor is an addition built on to a *very old* house, no natural lighting source at all. There are 3 light fixtures along the ceiling, all separately switched. Some of the residents we have here have mobility issues and other impairments, and while the ends of the hallways tend to stay lit adequately, the middle length of the hallway is pitch-dark when the light is off which usually frustrates me because I don't want anyone falling or otherwise injuring themselves because of the dark.

My question here, is can I just remove the switch and cap the wires together in the box, so long as it is properly grounded? I know all bedrooms, baths and common areas require permanent, switched lighting fixtures, but do I have any leeway with a hallway that is dependent on light fixtures? I don't particularly ever like the idea of any live circuit that can't be quickly and manually opened but I also don't like the possibility someone could fall if they have poor eyesight.

Also just to clarify, this is in regards to North American electrical code.

Comment: Just put lockable covers over the switches.

Comment: If you are concerned about folks tampering with the wiring in the boxes I would purchase tamper resistant screws. There are many different types. Nothing is fool proof in this area but making it difficult to get the cover plate off is the best option for most things , lockable covers in my opinion invite vandalism, but a blank cover plate with a security or tamper proof screws holding it in place no one tends to mess with. I can say this as college kids are the worst and I supported multiple properties part time for close to 20 years, I know the bit sets are cheap but kids usually don’t use em

Comment: Note if you go with LED lamps or fixtures make sure to get ones that are DLC approved, many of the cheap junk ones state 50000 hour LED’s but the drivers don’t make more than a few months. DLC or design Light Consortium requires a 5 year warranty and the very few failures I have had with these lamps and fixtures were promptly replaced.

Answer (score 6):

The problem comes in with the type of fixture, a ballast requires a switch or local disconnecting means in the fixture depending on the type of construction.  an Edison lamp (screw in) would be ok. Having a light on all the time actually is ok by code but some fixtures like fluorescents that have ballasts require a way to disconnect the power locally . I would not be concerned in any occupancy to do this but label the blank plate where the switch was what it used to control. My personal preference would to be to add an occupancy sensor up at the lamp. Any movement turns the light on from 1 to 20 minutes on the models I use.saves power and I support several hundred in my plant and only have 1 or 2 a year fail in really nasty conditions.

Comment: Thankfully, it's just a regular incandescent 60W bulb. It's funny you mentioned the fluorescent ballasts, because some properties also have those as a primary source of lighting and I suspected those being permanently wired on would be a big no-no! That said, the occupancy sensor is also a great idea, thank you very much!

Comment: BTW: if you're wondering what that local disconnecting means its called, look up a "ballast disconnect"

Comment: Screw-in fluorescent bulbs and motion sensors are exactly what they had in my parents senior living place.+

Comment: A CFL would be ok and I have quick disconnects inside my T5  and T8 light fixtures as 1 control device turns on many fixtures. 20 amp 3 phase control O heck let’s just say it is a but load of fixtures at 277v.  But even that can be done with a simple switch or disconnect at each fixture. I agree thanks three phase I can only think what they look like right now but some have a switch+ Today I go to LED’s for Edison  , it’s been a long day and having a tough time with my service.+, hope this made it

Comment: I believe you need a local disconnecting means even if they're on a switch. I'll tell you this: It makes it a lot easier to service the lights!  1 breaker off 2 install mains side of disconnect 3 breaker on lights on 4 work with all the other lights on

Comment: @ Harper yes a switch like a pull string or disconnect is required , I tried to say that but it was not clear . But I did state that after 3 phases comment.

Comment: @Netflixandkrill If you've got incandescent lamps/bulbs, then they only last hundreds of hours before blowing.  Replacing a lamp with the circuit energised might not be wise.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have the code citation, but I know, from numerous other questions and personal experience, the following:

The basic concept is **not** "Thou shalt have switched lights everywhere", but rather "Thou shalt have *lights on when you need them* everywhere". That can take a few forms:

- Switched lights with the switches in accessible (not too high or too low) standard locations - e.g., typically near doorways and at the top and bottom of stairs.
- Lights activated by motion detectors so that they go on without you having to flip a switch.
- Lights that are always on.

Until recently, the cost of electricity plus the cost of replacing bulbs (8,760 hours per year meant several replacements per year with incandescent, once a year or two with fluorescent) was such that in many situations, especially residential, the last thing you'd want to do is leave the lights on all the time.

However:

- Leaving lights on all the time is quite standard (I believe required by building codes) for *commercial* buildings. Typically this takes the form of one light per room (I assume some minimum requirements specified regarding lumens/square foot, etc.) always on with the rest of the lights switched.
- With LED fixtures, the electricity usage, and therefore the electricity cost, is far lower than with older lighting technologies. In addition, good quality LED lighting can last for several years between replacements. (As an example, my synagogue had nearly all the fluorescent and other lighting replaced a few years ago with the costs (parts & labor) paid for by the local electric utility as an energy saving (= lower peak demand, which is what the utilities really care about) measure. Then a few months ago, with almost all the LED lights installed the first time still working fine, we went through the same process again - all paid by the electric utility - and ended up with noticeably brighter lights and even lower energy usage.)

**So go for it! Lighting either always on or using a motion detector is a great way to improve safety.** Note that if you use a motion detector then you do have to make sure it works properly with LED bulbs ("neutral vs. leakage").

By the way, you do **not** need to cap the wires. If you are concerned about someone turning off the light **on purpose** then that is the way to go. But if you are just concerned about accidental (instinct) flips of the switch, get [a decent light switch cover](https://amzn.to/2NjesTh):
[image]

and there are varieties for Decora, etc. The key is that keeps the switch available for when you need it (e.g., bulb replacement).

Since you mentioned in a comment "60W incandescent bulb", just go ahead and replace it with an [LED bulb](https://amzn.to/2QIh4w7) to start saving energy. Otherwise it will cost you more - until that incandescent bulb burns out.

[image]

In addition, with LEDs there are options besides standard screw-in Edison bulbs. This can improve longevity, particularly if bulbs are subject to theft or vandalism. The catch is that installation is a little more involved then "screw in a new bulb", so you want to go for quality rather than just price. I have learned that myself the hard way (but I must say that Home Depot has very good return policies within the warranty period...) and that is extra important for anything installed "elsewhere" rather than in your own house. Not specifically recommending this one (GE is a good brand but you really need to pick what works for you), but [light fixtures like this](https://amzn.to/2Nghojs):
[image]
typically come with a much longer expected lifetime (this one says 50,00 hours) and warranty (5 years) and basically designing a complete *fixture* rather than trying to cram LED power supply & driver electronics into the base of a bulb can provide much better results than a simple bulb. Certainly for *new* installations, LED fixtures like this make sense. In another generation, [light bulb jokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbulb_joke) will lose their meaning!

Comment: First off, great reply, and thank you for the input! As for the desire to cap the wires, yes, I want to do that *specifically* to deter tampering. The residences I maintain are not regular rentals, they're board and lodges, which house people who usually suffer from various degrees of mental and physical disabilities, substance abuse disorders etc. Vandalism and tampering occurs regularly at these properties (most commonly the smoke detectors, followed by plumbing). Because of this, ensuring the wiring is both tamper-proof and safe is a huge priority.

Comment: @Netflixandkrill Then absolutely cap the wiring. Long-term. Adding a bit more about bulbs.

Comment: I'm tempted to twist them together, solder, apply liquid electrical tape to the bare wires and *then* cap them, because I can just imagine someone will probably try to mess with them at some point, even if I go the motion sensor and LED bulb route (which I might, the utility bills at just a single house can be upwards of 5-7K a month!) Also, thanks for the suggestions on the bulb...that recessed LED bulb looks nice, and like less of a pain than the recessed lighting fixtures we have at home (about half of them I have replaced with LED fixtures, and I absolutely hated working with them!)

Comment: While the electronics hobbyist (and actually occasionally for $) likes the "solder etc." method, Harper and others have made it extremely clear that **you can't do that with mains electricity**. Just use a standard Ideal wire nut of the right size and it will be fine. The one catch, unfortunately, is that you can't drywall over the switch plate - you have to leave a blank cover plate - every junction has to be accessible.

Comment: You can solder mains wiring *provided* you use correct mains solder-splicing techniques, but the more common way of making an irreversable connection at mains is using a *compression sleeve*, with a heatshrink insulator on top.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not 100% confident a wire nut by itself would deter tampering with this light, which is why I floated the idea. I've soldered on mains wiring before, but only under very specific conditions and with a properly secured splice

Comment: Are you saying that "residents" would: **Open a blank plate and start pulling out wires and pull off wire nuts?**

Comment: Haha, it sounds crazy but where this light is concerned, I wouldn't be surprised! I've tried putting signs up right next to the switch saying "leave this light on please," come back 2 minutes later and it's off. We've had tweakers sneak in to the utility closet, tamper with the boiler and flood part of the house before because they thought they should take it upon themselves to try and "fix" things that weren't to their liking, and I have a feeling this hallway light is the next iteration of this problem. Crazy as it sounds, I'm being 100% serious!

Comment: ...my current hypothesis is that it's because some of the troublemakers are in that part of the house, and keeping those hallway lights off assists them in their shenanigans. Specifically I think it's so that nobody can tell they are under the influence because drugs and alcohol are prohibited on our properties. Other times, it's sneaking people into their rooms.

Comment: Drugs + alcohol + opening electrical junction boxes and messing with wires = "room available"/Darwin award.

Comment: Exactly.  Drug activity is not uncommon around these properties. Residents are required to have their medications locked up in a cabinet and given by staff, Rx controlled substances locked in a safe and documented, etc. Tampering and vandalism is usually associated with substance use, like the above-mentioned smoke detectors (because people can't be bothered to go smoke pot outside) and when the state inspectors come through, there is without exception at least one smoke detector that has been unplugged or broken.

Comment: ...in one of the houses, in fact, I've even found a smoke alarm that had been very *meticulously* altered to have the speaker's connection removed from the circuit, whilst still appearing to be intact and functional (green LED showing power), which wasn't discovered until staff went to test it (required by law at least a couple times a month) only to find out the alarm wouldn't sound.

Comment: If you've got people opening junction boxes, then you need to up the ante - steel box covers and high security Torx machine screws.  I would not solder to prevent tampering, because then that gets in *your* way, and forces you to cut away wire length every time you modify it.

Comment: *I've tried putting signs up right next to the switch saying "leave this light on please," come back 2 minutes later and it's off.* Because that's a political statement: you are saying the environment and energy conservation does not matter, and that what the switcher was taught by their parents from age 4 is wrong.   All that is true, in the sense that your safety requirement takes priority, but the sanctimonious do not care about the big picture.

Comment: @manassehkatz = "room available"/you got evicted.

Comment: I'm one step ahead of you on the Torx security screws!  I have used them on the keypad-locked entry door because people were taking the battery out of it so it couldn't be locked (tbh, I don't think those are really appropriate for these types of houses anyway)

Comment: Sounds like what you really need are some nearly-hidden cameras.

Comment: In the UK we have 'secret key' switches eg https://www.tradingdepot.co.uk/mk-20-amp-dp-1-way-secret-key-switch-white used for emergency lighting testing, so the lights can't be turned off/on by ordinary people.

Comment: Not just for emergency lighting testing (the one you linked is engraved for emergency lighting testing, but you can get unengraved ones too), but also for switching regular lights and appliances that you don't want ordinary folks to mess with. They won't stop someone determined though.

Answer (score 5):

What the Code prohibits is exactly what you're complaining about: having to venture into a pitch dark space because the light switch is on the far side of it.

So what you want isn't optional; it's probably *mandatory* to use one of these cures:

- Multi-way switching so the space can be lit from either end
- Competent motion sensors to do it for you
- Hardwired on 24x7, otherwise some energy-saver will insist on turning them off.

However, building codes in some states may prohibit a 24x7 light for conservation reasons.

*You certainly should not use incandescent lights 24x7.  Even if you're full-on hard lifestyle committed to incandescent til the government pries it out of your cold dead hands, there are practical problems.  a) the stupid-huge power consumption of a 24x7 light: expect $1 per watt per year. And b) 24x7 you'll burn through the life of the bulb very quickly, making the space unsafe due to frequent bulb burnout.  Your best bet on both fronts is a quality build LED.*

Comment: We're starting to lean towards the motion-sensor and LED idea, since it was suggested earlier. Wiring a 2-way switch, adding another switch to the circuit is likely to be a nightmare (if you saw my thread about the dryer, which has links to images of the breaker panel it runs to, you'll understand lol. It's the same house and the wiring is...ghastly.) The switch that's already there is in the midde of the hallway, underneath the light it operates so that just means even more mental energy I'd have to expend trying to figure out how to run the wire without a disaster.

Comment: @Netflixandkrill Rest assured I am no proponent of "steam-era" multi-way switching for this, I'm just including all the legal options for completeness' sake. **What I do, myself, in that instance, is burn the light 24x7** because LED.   Since it's 2020 not 1920, there's no need to alter existing wiring, if you want multi-way switching, smart switches with powerline or wireless comms, set up so any switch turns on all lights. Easy peasy.  A motion sensor could be part of that network so the hand switch only needs to be a backup.

Comment: That would also be a good idea, except that there are 2 rooms that open right into that part of the hallway (where it is darkest), so I am a bit reluctant to leave them (and future occupants) at the mercy of the last person to pass through the hallway. And of course, to complicate things more the switch that is currently there is located on a wall that is at a 35° angle to the rest of the hallway...I think before the addition it must have been a bay window, because the alcove is shaped exactly like that is what was there before.

Comment: As this is commercial residential in my state the light is required to be on 24x7 or motion controlled, I think the 2020 updates do require occupancy sensors but that is only a draft so far for my state and they usually approve with the new code by mid year, I think it was October in 17. (Oregon is my state).

Comment: @Netflixandkrill Given your environment, I wouldn't do anything that leaves anything to the inmates, and I would also strive for a solution that lets the sneakies have their dark most of the time. They'll stop objecting to a motion sensor once they realize it's an early warning system.

Comment: There are key-operated swtiches that can replace normal switches - I first saw them long ago in high school for corrridor lights and other areas that only the custodians could control.

Comment: @Harper you make a good point, there. Above all else, safety is always my biggest concern. In this scenario, though, that also means making sure residents can't in turn jeopardize the safety of others. For example, at one house I was asked to install some old gym shower room lockers in the garage for storage, but they were meant to drill right in to the stud from the back side. Since this was also a place where we had (at the time) the most drug and alcohol related incidents, I also chose to weld joist hangers on top of the rear part, so they couldn't be tipped over...just stuff like that

Comment: ...this was of course only an option because the sides of the studs were exposed. And many of them took a few passes owing to how thin the stud hangers were versus the slightly heavier gauge of the lockers themselves! Still, so far nobody has ripped them off the hangers so that's good!